# Sending request in axios request interceptor doesen't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, token

I'm trying to send a request in an Axios request interceptor. I need to wait for that request to finish before sending any other request. (The use case is refreshing an access_token)

The problem is the request never gets sent and throws an `undefined` exception.

Here is what I'm doing:

Registering an interceptor:

`api.interceptors.request.use(handleInterceptRequest);`

Using that interceptor to check for an expired token before every request:

```
async function handleInterceptRequest(config) {
  if(config.url === '/auth/refresh'){
    return false;
  }

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const token = store.getState().app.token;

    //Check if token has expired:
    if (token && Date.now() / 1000 >= jwtDecode(token).exp) {
      try{
        //Token has expired - trigger method below to send a refresh request and save the new token
        await refreshToken(token);
      } catch(error){
        reject(error); // error is caught here but is undefined
      }
    }
    //Only when everything is finished resolve the requst config and let other requests pass
    resolve(config);
  });
}

async function refreshToken(prevToken) {
  //Trying to send the request (The destructiring is not the issue)
  const { data :  { access_token } } = await api({
    url: '/auth/refresh',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${prevToken}`
    }
  });

  //I never get here
  api.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
  setItem('token', access_token);
  store.dispatch(setToken(access_token));
  return access_token;
}
```

The refresh request never gets sent and an exception is thrown. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

I also tried doing something like this instead in the refreshToken function:

This works:

```
async function refreshToken(prevToken) {
  const data = await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo');
    }, 1000);
  });

  return data;
}
```

This doesen't work:

```
async function refreshToken(prevToken) {
  const { data } = await api({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    data: {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    }
  });


  return data;
}
```

So there is definitely something wrong with this interceptor setup that doesen't let the axios request even start.

Thanks

Comment: does it call refreshToken ?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb yes it does but it never gets past the line where the axios request is atempted. See the 'I never get here' comment. Also it throws the undefined exception (see the catch in the intercept method)